# 1-day old kubuntu 15.10 doesn't close windows even though the program is closed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, window-manager

Dear ladies and gentlemen,
After a fresh install of Kubuntu 15.10 and some installations including Nvidia driver 352 from repos in order to switch to Zotac GeForce GTX750, some windows will not close properly when closed by clicking the "X".
The program is terminated, i guess, but the window stays as a zombie. just the graphical window.

I'm not really a professional here, please ask for details if needed to solve this problem.
xprop and pointing on one of those zombies shows:

```
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Arbeitsfläche — Plasma"
_KDE_NET_WM_USER_CREATION_TIME(CARDINAL) = 36074
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x2, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP
_XEMBED_INFO(_XEMBED_INFO) = 0x0, 0x1
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x1800002
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
                Client accepts input or input focus: True
                Initial state is Normal State.
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 1085
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 25165841
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "plasmashell", "plasmashell"
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
                user specified location: 0, 0
                user specified size: 1680 by 1050
                program specified minimum size: 1680 by 1050
                program specified maximum size: 1680 by 1050
                window gravity: Static
```

Comment: Eeeer, I don't know what exactly happened... I played around in the compositing configurations and set on openGL 3.1. Everything was f***ed up. switching back and rebooting kinda fixed the mentioned problem. Running now. Will post this as solution when it is a persistent fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eeeer, I don't know what exactly happened... I played around in the compositing configurations and set on openGL 3.1. Everything was f***ed up. switching back and rebooting kinda fixed the mentioned problem. Running now.
Kubuntu 15.10 seems like the most unstable release of an ubuntu distro I used since 8.04... very unconveniently unstable. Maybe i'm doing something wrong but I still recommend 14.04.01 LTS for nice and working release.